# Proving a statement about the determinant of tridiagonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, tridiagonal-matrices, toeplitz-matrices

The statement of the question is given below:

> [image]

In order to understand the meaning of tridiagonal, I tried to calculate the $4 \times 4$ matrix of the above description and I get the following matrix:

$$
\begin{vmatrix}
1&1&0&0\\
1&1&1&0\\
0&1&1&1\\
0&0&1&1
\end{vmatrix}
$$

Also, I tried to calculate the $3 \times 3$ matrix of the above description and I get the following matrix:

$$
\begin{vmatrix}
1&1&0\\
1&1&1\\
0&1&1\\
\end{vmatrix}
$$

So I can see why it is called tridiagonal matrix. And I know that the definition of the determinant of a matrix is as follows:

> [image]
>   [image]

But I still did not know how to prove the question, shall I prove it by induction on $k$? if so, how I can deal with proving the case of $k = n+1$? could anyone help me please?

**My idea:*

I think I can change the given matrix to an upper triangular matrix ? can this work?

Comment: That matrix is not merely tridiagonal, it is also Toeplitz. Its eigenvalues are known for any $n$.

Comment: But I do not want a proof using eigenvalues and eigenvectors@RodrigodeAzevedo

Comment: Getting the unwanted proof may boost morale and provide hints for the wanted proof.

Comment: Why should the entries not be from $\mathbb Q$? I hope you agree that $0, -1, 1$ are rational numbers.

Comment: Also, what are you reading?

Comment: I am sorry for my trivial question .... but the can also say that the entries from $\mathbb{R}$, $\mathbb{C}$ or $\mathbb{Z}.$ ..... it is "The Linear Algebra a Beginning Graduate Student Ought to Know" by Jonathan S. Golan @darijgrinberg

Comment: I mean " the author can also say ..... " @darijgrinberg

Comment: It says the question is duplicate : does the duplicate suffice?

Comment: yes it suffice thank you so much! :) @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг

Comment: You are welcome, thank you for intimating me